# How can I determine the size and file type of items stored in a content database?

Tags: sql, content

I'm a SQL Server person, and I'm wondering why one of our SharePoint content databases suddenly shot up to 600GB.  I suspect we're adding larger documents, rather than more.
Is there a SQL query I can run to determine what type of files, how many and how many versions of them we're storing?

Comment: Querying the database is not a recommended approach. You'd want to use Powershell or the server object model to run this analysis.

Answer (score 1):

One thing, keep in mind.it is unsupported to run the queries against the Content DBs.

You can track the Storage with couple of ways.

- get the list of All site collections
- Now from central admin check the Site storage either central admin or powershell
- Now sum up and compare with Content DB size.

From here you will get the largest site collection.
Now from that site collection you can see the [Storage metrics](http://sharepointhoster.com/how-do-i-track-my-storage-usage-in-sharepoint-2013.html) of the site collection.

Also, please note this. If auditing is turned on then that storage will not be recorded on the site collection. In that case, i would run a report against that Content DB ..by table size.

Please check this: [Get SharePoint Library Size with PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/01/get-sharepoint-library-size-powershell.html)